# Backbone.js: Populating my collection and then appending it to the page

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am working in backbone.js. In the following code I am making a call to the Nutritionix API in order to populate my collection with the JSON response. I am having trouble populating my collection and appending the result as a list. I am doing this in order to test if my collection has been properly populated and in order to test that it will append to the page. However when I test the code out in the browser I don't see the field[brand_name] attribute appended to the page. Is my collection properly populated? How can I see the  aformentioned attribute appended to the page? What is wrong with my code?

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(function(){

    var SearchList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/taco?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%2Cbrand_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_id&appId=26952a04&appKey=78e2b31849de080049d26dc6cf4f338c",

        initialize: function(){
            this.bind("reset", function(model, options){
            console.log("Inside event");
            console.log(model);
            });
        }

    });

    var terms = new SearchList();

    terms.fetch({
        success: function(response,xhr) {
             console.log("Inside success");
             console.log(response.toJSON());
        },
        ERROR: function (errorResponse) {
               console.log(errorResponse)
        }
    });


    // The main view of the application
    var App = Backbone.View.extend({

        // Base the view on an existing element
        el: $('.container'),

        initialize: function(){

            this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);

            // Cache these selectors
            // this.total = $('#total span');
            this.list = $('#listing');


        },

        render: function(){

            // Calculate the total order amount by agregating
            // the prices of only the checked elements
            terms.each(function(term){

                this.list.append("<li>"+ term.get('field[brand_name]')+"</li>");

            }, this);

        }
    });

});
```

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Interactive Food Guide</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="searchBox"> <br/><br/>
        </div>
        <ul id="listing"></ul>
    </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Backbone and Underscore -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <!-- apps functionality -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the structure of each term is `{ 'field[brand_name]' : value }` ? I haven't used backbone in over a year, so I'm not sure if its getter method can parse 'field[brand_name]' for an object `{ field: { brand_name } }`

Comment: I'm not sure, It might be field.brand_name

Comment: Hi @RSB if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see some errors in the code:

1. JSON returned by url is an object, and what you should charge in the collection is the array "hits" that is inside the object. The logic of this process is defined in the method "parse" the collection.
2. The collection was declared out of view. When indicated in view to listen to your collection, you will have problems because the fetch method call before the view can be instantiated, so the view does not realize when the fetch is executed

Here is your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/04y8rmj0/6/) with comments.

```
$(function(){

var SearchList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/taco?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%2Cbrand_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_id&appId=26952a04&appKey=78e2b31849de080049d26dc6cf4f338c",

    initialize: function(){

    },

    //** 1. Function "parse" is a Backbone function to parse the response properly
    parse:function(response){           
        //** return the array inside response, when returning the array
        //** we left to Backone populate this collection
        return response.hits;
    }

});

   // The main view of the application
var App = Backbone.View.extend({

    // Base the view on an existing element
    el: $('.container'),

    initialize: function(){

        //** 2. the view must listen to an object inside in the view
        //** so we create a new instance of SearchList and save it into model var of the view
        this.model = new SearchList();
        this.model.fetch();

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);

        // Cache these selectors
        // this.total = $('#total span');
        this.list = $('#listing');
    },

    render: function(){
        //** 2. Continue
        var terms = this.model;

        // Calculate the total order amount by agregating
        // the prices of only the checked elements
        terms.each(function(term){

            this.list.append("<li>"+ term.get('fields')["brand_name"]+"</li>");

        }, this);

    }
});

//** Create an instance of the view to start the program
var foo = new App();
```

});

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue here is that you forgot to instantiate your app:

```
new App();
```

Secondly you need to refer to your data with the correct structure:

```
term.get('hits')
```

As term is the model, which contains an array of **hits**

Lastly, you need your collection in your view, and listen for the sync on your views collection:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
```

I updated your app.js like so:

```
$(function(){

var SearchList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/taco?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%2Cbrand_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_id&appId=26952a04&appKey=78e2b31849de080049d26dc6cf4f338c",

    initialize: function(){
        this.bind("reset", function(model, options){
        console.log("Inside event");
        console.log(model);
        });
    }

});

// The main view of the application
var App = Backbone.View.extend({

    // Base the view on an existing element
    el: $('.container'),

    initialize: function () {

        this.collection = new SearchList();

        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function (response, xhr) {
                console.log("Inside success");
                console.log(response.toJSON());
            },
            ERROR: function (errorResponse) {
                console.log(errorResponse)
            }
        });

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);

        // Cache these selectors
        // this.total = $('#total span');
        this.list = $('#listing');


    },

    render: function(){

        var context = this;
        this.collection.each(function (term) {
            _.each(term.get('hits'), function (item) {
                context.list.append("<li>" + item.fields.brand_name + "</li>");
            });

        }, this);

    }
});
new App();
});
```

The correct way is not to use **var context = this;** but an element on your view. I just wanted to point you in the right direction :-)